# Can you integrate GCP labels into dbt sql?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dbt

I am trying to add GCP labels to my dbt sql files and running into some errors.

In the BigQuery UI you can prepend any query with label key/value pairs like this:
SET @@query_label = "key1:value1,key2:value2";

I know the keys and values I am using are correct because they work in the UI.

Is there anything in how dbt parses/processes the sql that could be failing due to the @@ symbols?

I tried adding SET @@query_label = "key1:value1,key2:value2"; after the config section and it fails

Answer (score 1):

You can specify labels for the views and tables you create. These labels need to be provided in either the `dbt_project.yml` file, or within the model config. See the examples below:

```yaml
# this is your dbt_project.yml

models:
  your_project:
    marketing:
      +labels:
        domain: marketing
        another_key: another_value
    finance:
      +labels:
        domain: finance
```

```sql
-- in the config of the model
{{
  config(
    materialized = "table",
    labels = {'domain': 'finance'}
  )
}}

select * from {{ ref('fct_revenue') }}
```

You can find more information in the docs [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs#labels-and-tags).

Comment: Thank you! I found that documentation. That would only label the output view and tables for BQ storage, but what about the actual processing? Or would that get attributed to the view/table? I'm asking because processing accounts for the majority of my cost and want that labeled

Comment: The best you can do is to try out what I proposed, and test it yourself.